# Call super in constructor and assign a field in Kotlin?

Tags: constructor, kotlin

I would like to initialise `status` field inside constructor apart of calling `super`.

```
class MyException : RuntimeException {

    init {
        val status: Status
    }

    constructor(status: Status) : super()

    constructor(status: Status, cause: Throwable) : super(cause)

}
```

How can I achievie that?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but you can find everything about constructors and the `init` block here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors

Comment: @zsmb13 I've read it but I didn't find any info about my case. I believe that it's trivial but I don't know exact kotlin syntax to achieve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That worked for me:

```
class MyException : RuntimeException {
    val status: Status

    constructor(status: Status) : super() {
        this.status = status
    }

    constructor(status: Status, cause: Throwable) : super(cause) {
        this.status = status
    }
}
```